# Own Theme custom CSS does not display in editor but works in page

Tags: themes, css

I started making my own theme. So far, everything has been working just fine.

On the Main Page (Static Page) of my Blog, I created a couple of headlines with text, and i also created a div. I was very happy to be able to apply a custom CSS style to, via the Editor in the Design Menu in the backend.

My first problem was, that when I checked my page while beeing logged-in in Wordpress, the changes were not visible.

When i checked again without being logged in, everything worked fine.

The other Problem is, that now the CSS Code I applied to the div is not visible either in my `style.css` file on the server, neither in the Custom CSS Editor in the WordPress backend

Is this normal? Is there any specific code required? Is there a smarter way to start with?

Since I don't know what specific part of code is wrong, I will post it when somebody has an idea.

Comment: What theme are you using? Are you working in a child theme?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes


Does your host have Cashe enabled? If so turn off while making changes

Comment: As I said, I‘m making my own theme, so im not working in a child theme. How do I turn Cashe of?